# Store all link urls in an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, url, search

I'm trying to parse through a html document and store the urls in an array with php.  If for example the source code of the document is:

```
Blah blah blah <a href="http://google.com">link</a> blab
<a href="http://yahoo.com">more links</a> ababasadsf
```

How do I find and grab the href attribute of the links and store each as an array element?

Answer (score 3):

Using [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), you can traverse the DOM and find the anchors (`<a>`) with the `href` attribute defined:

```
$dom = phpQuery::newDocument($htmlSource);
$anchors = $dom->find('a[href]');

$urls = array();

if($anchors) {
  foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    $anchor = pq($anchor);
    $urls[] = $anchor->attr('href');
  }
}
```